# How does a plus one on a post carrying a link, help for SEO?

Tags: seo, google-plus

How does a `+1` on a post (from Google Plus) that carries a link help for SEO? Will it help the PageRank in Google? If yes, how?

Comment: It may be because it is late, but I am not understanding the question. Can you give an example or clarification? Perhaps someone else will get it better than I seem to be.

Comment: @SuhailGupta Do you mean does a +1 on a Google+ post containing a link to your site help with your SEO results?

Comment: Not much significant seo benefit but the more +1 shall means more follow link to your page.

Comment: @dan yeah.if there is a g+ page that is linked to a website..that page posts consistently and gets likes..the posts are mixed..they don't always carry a back link to the pages of the linked website..how all this is helpful to _seo_ ?

Comment: @Peter I didn't get you

Comment: @SuhailGupta Pluses and likes are generally considered to send _social signals_, and it's suggested that Google might use them as a metric, but they're not direct ranking factors. Indirectly, the pluses might cause readers to click on the links within the post that contains them, increasing traffic to them, and thus increasing popularity for a page/site.

Comment: @dan For what purpose, Google might use the count of `+1` as a metric ?

Comment: Maybe the Q title could be re-worded to something like this: How does Google use social indicators, like +1, to affect its SERPs? And the body changed to match. That's a Q i'd like to ask, but i don't mind if Suhail grabs it. Is it a useful/better Q?

Comment: @martinf I posted a new question with this title.

Answer (score 2):

1. At one time, you were able to get DoFollow links from Google Plus. However, that has since been "fixed" and nofollow has been implemented on all external links.
2. For the past four or five years, the term "Social Signals" has been used to describe links/likes/shares from social networking websites. It is believed that these social signals can have an impact on your website's search rankings.

All in all - One share (+1) probably has a very minimal impact. However, social links are great in the sense that they can have a knock-on effect. i.e. Person visits your website via a link on Facebook and likes the content so much that they share it on their blog (not to mention the fact that nofollow links are a vital part of a healthy backlink portfolio).

Answer (score 1):

PageRank alone != SEO.

Google attempt to rank by relevance, and PageRank is a single signal of that.

Google rarely reveal all the signals they use to rank a site, but the fact they own all Google Plus' data, would mean I would find it would be odd for them not to mine it to help improve their search results.

A popular site will be +1d, retweeted and liked - which are all good signals that a site is popular though, like links, open to abuse from spammers.

It is also good free advertising.  Who cares *how* people find your site (whether it be via a Google Plus profile or via search), as long as the right people do so.